# How do I programmatically set pointer permissions on a CLP in Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform

I'd like to set pointer permissions on a CLP using either the REST API or the JS SDK so I can automate the process. Is this possible?

The documentation discusses [pointer permissions](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#pointer-permissions), but doesn't show how to implement them AFAIK. From the linked docs:

> Pointer permissions are a special type of class-level permission that create a virtual ACL on every object in a class, based on users stored in pointer fields on those objects. For example, given a class with an `owner` field, setting a read pointer permission on `owner` will make each object in the class only readable by the user in that object’s `owner` field.

How do I achieve the above programmatically? As in, if I have an object with an `owner` property that stores a `User` pointer, how do I set a CLP to make this object only readable by the `owner`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by searching through the Parse Server source. [This test suite](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/2d257e20a00ac031919fc41940289e8bd2ac60d9/spec/PointerPermissions.spec.js) demonstrates pointer permission usage.

When adding a CLP to object schema, you can set pointer permissions by including the pointer names in the `readUserFields` and `writeUserFields` properties of the CLP. Here's an example:

```js
const exampleSchema = new Parse.Schema('Example')

exampleSchema
  .addString('content')
  .addPointer('owner', '_User')

const clp = {
  create: { '*': true },
  readUserFields: ['owner'],
  writeUserFields: ['owner']
}

exampleSchema.setCLP(clp)

await exampleSchema.save()
```

The above creates schema for the `Example` object. It allows anyone to create an `Example`, but only allows the user set in the `owner` property to read or write the object.

Answer (score 0):

It can be set in Parse Dashboard by clicking on the class and then choosing "Security" from the menu on the right.

[found on Parse Community](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/where-to-place-the-pointer-permissions-json/887)

Comment: Unfortunately this approach isn't programmatic. I'd like to be able to automate setting pointer permissions on CLPs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```js
const schema = new Parse.Schema("MyClass");

schema.setCLP({
  "find": {
    "requiresAuthentication": true,
    "role:admin": true
  },
  "get": {
    "requiresAuthentication": true,
    "role:admin": true
  },
  "create": { "role:admin": true },
  "update": { "role:admin": true },
  "delete": { "role:admin": true }
});

await schema.update();
```

You will need to use the Node.js SDK and initialize it with master key.

Comment: Pointer permissions don't seem to be used in this example. I've updated my question to make things more clear.